# Javascript sum values in 3 objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hi I'm trying to sum the values I have in 3 json objects.

```
var things = {
    "noun": {
        "syn": ["belongings", "holding", "stuff", "property"]
    }
};
var stuff = {
    "noun": {
        "syn": ["belongings", "holding", "property"]
    }
};
var crap = {
    "noun": {
        "syn": ["things", "holding", "waste"]
    }
};

result = {};
word1 = things.noun.syn
for (key in word1) {
    nk = word1[key];
    if (result.nk == undefined) {
        result.nk = 1
    } else {
        result.nk = result.nk + 1;
    }
}
console.log(result);​
```

The result I am getting is `result.nk` instead of `result.belongings` for example.

I've been screwing around in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qunUz/2/

How do I sum the amount of times each value appears?

Comment: btw, you should not use for-in loops to iterate over arrays. Use a regular for loop or the forEach method instead.

Comment: @missingno i thought you were supposed to use for-in for objects? (its not an array). Am i wrong?

Comment: Well, in the code you wrote `word1` is an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a property given a string value you should use bracket notation

```
result[nk] //access the property defined by nk's value
```

instead of the dot notation you are using

```
result.nk     //access the 'nk' property
result['nk']  //equivalent in bracket notation.
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting result.nk you are not using the variable `nk` but really `result.nk`.

You should store it like this:

```
result[nk] = 1;
```

Like demonstrated on the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qunUz/3/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do. The following will sum up the occurrences of each value in your three different arrays.

```
var a = things.noun.syn.concat(stuff.noun.syn).concat(crap.noun.syn);
var a = a.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  if (typeof acc[curr] == 'undefined') {
    acc[curr] = 1;
  } else {
    acc[curr] += 1;
  }

  return acc;
}, {});
```

Results in

```
belongings: 2
holding: 3
property: 2
stuff: 1
things: 1
waste: 1
```

If your target browser doesn't have a reduce function, you can use underscore.js (or just copy their reduce function).